# Different ways of Initializing list in Python

Tags: python

Might be a naive question but this troubled me a lot. I want to initialize a list with some default values. I consider the following 2 approaches to do so:

1.`cache1 = [[-1 for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]`
2. `cache2 = [[-1]*5]*]`

I was under the assumption that their behavior is exactly the same. However, when I execute the following commands:

```
cache1[0][0] = 100
cache2[0][0] = 100
```

The lists are updated to:

```
cache1 = [[100, -1, -1, -1, -1], [100, -1, -1, -1, -1], [100, -1, -1, -1, -1], [100, -1, -1, -1, -1], [100, -1, -1, -1, -1]]
cache2 = [[100, -1, -1, -1, -1], [100, -1, -1, -1, -1], [100, -1, -1, -1, -1], [100, -1, -1, -1, -1], [100, -1, -1, -1, -1]]
```

Can someone please point out what is the difference between the two initializations? Thank you

Comment: cache2 = [[-1]*5]*] is wrong, do you mean [[[-1]*5]*5]?

Comment: my bad,
yes, I meant cache2 =  [[[-1]*5]*5]